# Programming StyleCop rules with instrospector-similar-program

Tags: c#, fxcop, stylecop

I am currently in the process of developing my own StyleCop rules to enforce coding standards and best practices.

Because I am still learning the "StyleCop way of thinking", I was wondering if there is a similar program as [Introspector for FxCop](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/introspector.html), but then targeted for StyleCop.

Is there such a program or is there only the SDK-helpfile to guide you in developing StyleCop rules?

Comment: If i doubleclick a stylecop file I get a window like the following: http://i.imgur.com/uaQpXFB.png I was pretty sure this is included in standard stylecop installation, is it not? Or were you looking for something different?

Comment: That is the settingsfile used to configure which rules you want to execute on using StyleCop. I am developing my own rules and am looking for some help writing them. With FxCop-ruledevelopment, there is a great tool showing you exactly how to program towards various aspects in your code. I am hoping there is a similar tool for StyleCop-ruledevelopment.